# Python 3 Syntax Changes

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x, python-2.x

So my work which had used older Python 2 is doing some code updating, anyways I am just learning python and am actually pretty new here, but what are the major syntax changes that went from 2-->3

Or is there really even that much syntax changes at all (like I know print got changed, but what else MAJOR)

Thanks

Comment: use 2to3 : http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html

Comment: For casual use, `print` is probably the thing you will notice the most. If you do any sort of unicode handling, that's very different. Other than that, it should mostly be stuff you can get used to quite quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What’s New In Python 3.0:
http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

PEP: 3000 - Python 3000:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3000/

PEP: 3099 - Things that will Not Change in Python 3000:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099/

Comment: The first one is important. There have been several changes in semantics - most should cause the code to fail fast (e.g. using the result of `zip` or `range` as a list), but there might be some subtle ones.

Answer (score 5):

Did you read this: [Overview of Syntax Changes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#overview-of-syntax-changes) ?

Comment: Ya I read the Overview, but it doesn't really state specifics

Answer (score 4):

The things you really notice in the syntax are the print statement, and the change in the exception syntax. 2to3 will handle all that.

**That won't cause you any headaches though. Those generally come from the split of strings into binary bytes and Unicode strings. 2to3 doesn't handle that.**

So the changes in syntax aren't really what you need to worry about. :)

Then there are some minor changes in the syntax, tons of small changes in various functionality and a huge reorganization of the standard library, most of which 2to3 handles.

There isn't any canonical summary of all changes afaik, although I've tried to [make one](http://python3porting.com/differences.html) in my [new book](http://python3porting.com/). There may be some misses, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do much better than to read the documentation: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/whatsnew/ covers all the changes pretty succienctly. Read the "What’s New In Python 3.0" section first for the main changes.